# difference between document.ready() inner function and a function in <script></script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these two functions?

1:

```
$(document).ready(function myfunc() {
   function dosomething() {
      // do something
   }
});
```

2:

```
<script language="javascript">
function dosomething() {
   // do something
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$(document).ready()` function executes when the DOM has finished loading. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Whereas the function is not executed until called. If you were to have a call to that function, it would happen as it is loading and not wait for any external event to complete as in the former. Like:

```
<script language="javascript">
dosomething();
function dosomething(){
// do something
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, your inner function `dosomething()` will be limited to the scope of `myfunc()`.

In the second case, the `dosomething()` function will be added to the global space. It will be accessible from anywhere.

Comment: +1 The limited scope of functions in document ready seems to be overlooked and/or ignored by most.