# Are $(function(){}); and $("document").ready(function(){}); the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been enjoying Lynda.com's Jquery Essential Training, and I've noticed that in the beginning the instructor uses:

```
    Fig. 1

    $("document").ready(function(){
    fun stuff goes here
    });
```

However, somewhere along the line he starts using:

```
    Fig. 2

    $(function(){
    fun stuff goes here
    });
```

From the way he speaks, it sounds as if they are completely synonymous (some inherent jquery shorthand?) but as far as I can tell, it's never explicitly touched upon.

I'm sure someone could clear this up quickly for me. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657774/difference-between-document-ready-inner-function-and-a-function-in-script-sc) but I believe that question is slightly different--I understand the concept of calling a function on document ready versus one that is globally available; (those functions also have names.)

The instructor uses phantom functions (I think that was the term for a function without a name,) and when typing out Fig. 2, he says "So this will be on document ready..."

Comment: keep learning and let us if you come across any good stuff

Comment: not phantom function. Anonymous function!

Comment: Hahaha, in the FINAL chapter he touches on my question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are exactly the same, just aliases.

[From the jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(handler)
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> $(handler)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The default context is the document, so if you pass in some random mumbo jumbo string that does not reference an HTML node, it will be the document.

`$('fdsljkfdslj').context` is document. And because the default context is the document, this means you don't have to specify it and can just feed a function to jQuery, `$(function() { });`

And I think you mean `$(document)` instead, since specifying the string document isn't as popular, because `document` passes the real document object to jQuery. But again, this will be the same as passing nothing or mumbo jumbo string since we pass `document` literally.