# Is $(function() { }) an exact equivalent to $(document).ready(function() { })

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between these jQuery ready functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions)
>   [Are $(function(){}); and $(“document”).ready(function(){}); the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384651/are-function-and-document-readyfunction-the-same)
>   [start javascript code with $(function, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008843/start-javascript-code-with-function-etc)

Today, while reviewing some javascript code I found that some portions of code where written in a `$(function() { })` section, and other part of code where inside a `$(document).ready(function() { })` one. So my first reaction was: OK, What's the difference?

After a little of googling I found the next statement in the jQuery tutorial [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery):

> The following is a shortcut for the $(document).ready(callback) notation:

```
$(function() {
    // code to execute when the DOM is ready
});
```

Now, the question is: Is `$(function() { })` an exact equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { })`?

(And also a "less-global" indirect question will be: Is safe for me to put all the code in just one of the two sections?)

Comment: Refer to the API site when in doubt.. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Next time, please do at least some research before posting a question. You'd know the answer by [googling](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+jquery+document+ready+vs+%24), or after [looking in the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c3b1367f4c19abf12eadc1460a37dc34ae765e1b/src/core.js#L157).

Comment: Sorry, I swear that the duplicate question didn't show up when I search for the answer. This question should be closed for duplicated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `$(function() { })` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { })`.

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler)
```

From [`.ready()` reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 1):

`(function() { })` and `$(document).ready(function() { })` could be used interchangeably and its upto us to choose the one we like. I feel `$(document).ready(function() { })` mode readable and understandable when going through code.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are exactly the same and yes, it's safe to put both on the same block (assuming there's nothing relevant between them).