# Format of jQuery statements different than usual

Tags: jquery, syntax

I found a jquery program. Every code-line is like this -> jQuery("....). 
Example:

```
     jQuery(function(ready){....
```

Why is it done like this?

Comment: Are you asking why it's `jQuery(...)` instead of `$(...)`? They're synonyms.

Comment: `$` is just a shortcut, but other libraries use it as well, so some programmers prefer to use the long name to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Or if you're asking about why the argument is a function, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384651/are-function-and-document-readyfunction-the-same