# Difference between opening tags of jQuery and how it impacts code

Tags: jquery

What's the difference between beginning a jquery script with:

```
1. jQuery(function($){
2. (function($) {
3. jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
4. $(document).ready(function() {
```

And why if I use one prevents some part of the code from working while using another prevents another part of the code from working?

Comment: The second one is not the same, since it doesn't wait for the document to be ready. The other 3 are equivalent, unless you've reassigned `$` to something other than `jQuery`.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for three of those four. All three you listed are deprecated in favor of `$(function() { /*...*/ });` Your second one is probably the one that was breaking, because it doesn't wait for the "ready" event before running its code (if I make a reasonable assumption about how the code using it ends).

Comment: You could also use `jQuery($ => { ...` (if you don't use IE11)

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $( handler )
> $( document ).ready( handler )
> $( "document" ).ready( handler )
> $( "img" ).ready( handler )
> $().ready( handler )
> ```
>
> As of jQuery 3.0, only the first syntax is recommended; the other syntaxes still work but are deprecated.

See [this very closely related question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384651/are-function-and-document-readyfunction-the-same) for more about the ones above.

One of the ones you've listed isn't jQuery-specific. If I make a reasonable assumption about how you end it:

```
(function($) {
    // ...
})(jQuery);
```

...it won't wait for jQuery's "ready" event before running its code, it'll run immediately. I'm guessing that was the one that didn't work for you.

Note that if you control the `script` tag that runs your code, all of these are obsolete at best (and arguably unnecessary even years back): Instead, do one of the following (best first);

1. On modern browsers, use `type="module"` on your `script` tag so your code runs in an isolated module (and in strict mode). That will also defer running the code until after the DOM has been fully parsed (like `defer`, see #2).
2. Use `defer` on your `script` tag; the browser won't run the code until the DOM has been fully parsed. (Note: For this to work, your code must be in an external `.js` file, not inline within the `script` tag. [That's not true of `type="module"` above.])
3. If you have to support seriously obsolete browsers, put your `script` tag at the end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. That way, the code won't run until everything prior to it has been parsed and put in place.

Answer (score 1):

#2 doesn't wait for the document to be ready. It's an IIFE creating a local scope where `$` is bound (presumably to `jQuery` in the argument list), but the function is executed immediately (unless it contains a call like `$(function...)` or `$(document).ready(function...)`).

The other 3 wait for the document to be ready before executing the callback function. #1 and #3 can be used in a context where `$` has been assigned something other than `jQuery`; inside the callback function it will be bound to `jQuery` automatically. #4 assumes that `$` is `jQuery`.

See [Are $(function(){}); and $("document").ready(function(){}); the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384651/are-function-and-document-readyfunction-the-same?noredirect=1&lq=1) for information about the different ways of waiting for the document to be ready.